# Python: Combine array rows based on difference between prior row's last element and posterior row's first element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

---

As title, say I am given a (n, 2) numpy array recording a series of segment's start and end indices, for example n=6:

```
import numpy as np
# x records the (start, end) index pairs corresponding to six segments
x = np.array(([0,4],    # the 1st seg ranges from index 0 ~ 4
              [5,9],    # the 2nd seg ranges from index 5 ~ 9, etc.
              [10,13],
              [15,20],
              [23,30],
              [31,40]))
```

Now I want to combine those segments with small interval between them. For example, merge consecutive segments if the interval is no larger than 1, so desired output would be:

```
y = np.array([0,13],    # Cuz the 1st seg's end is close to 2nd's start, 
                        # and 2nd seg's end is close to 3rd's start, so are combined.
             [15,20],   # The 4th seg is away from the prior and posterior segs,
                        # so it remains untouched.
             [23,40])   # The 5th and 6th segs are close, so are combined
```

so that the output segments would turn out to be just three instead of six.
Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want a `numpy` solution or is any solution ok?

Comment: `numpy` is preferred anyway :)

Comment: @Thomas But any alternative other than numpy would be great tho

Answer (score 2):

If we're able to assume the segments are ordered and none are wholly contained within a neighbor, then you could do this by identifying where the gap between the end value in one range and the start of the next exceeds your criteria:

```
start = x[1:, 0]  # select columns, ignoring the beginning of the first range
end = x[:-1, 1]  # and the end of the final range
mask = start>end+1  # identify where consecutive rows have too great a gap
```

Then stitching these pieces back together:

```
np.array([np.insert(start[mask], 0, x[0, 0]), np.append(end[mask], x[-1, -1])]).T
Out[96]: 
array([[ 0, 13],
       [15, 20],
       [23, 40]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a NumPy vectorized solution -

```
def merge_boundaries(x):
    mask = (x[1:,0] - x[:-1,1])!=1
    idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)
    start = np.r_[0,idx+1]
    stop = np.r_[idx, x.shape[0]-1]
    return np.c_[x[start,0], x[stop,1]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [230]: x
Out[230]: 
array([[ 0,  4],
       [ 5,  9],
       [10, 13],
       [15, 20],
       [23, 30],
       [31, 40]])

In [231]: merge_boundaries(x)
Out[231]: 
array([[ 0, 13],
       [15, 20],
       [23, 40]])
```